# How to use presets for operator properties?

Tags: python, interface, operator

Is there a way to use Blender's preset system for operator attributes? I. e. preset menu inside operator redo panel (F6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable presets for an operator using the [`PRESET` option](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78c_release/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.bl_options).

eg:

```
class SomeTool(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.some_tool"
    bl_label = "Some Tool"
    bl_options = {'PRESET'}

    # - snip -
```

The preset directory will be set based on the operator name and created on demand.