# Can Python Operator Presets be shared between Operators?

Tags: python

I am currently working on an Add-on that makes use of the Preset system. As outlined [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81809/how-to-use-presets-for-operator-properties), Presets in an Operator can easily be defined using the `bl_options = {'PRESET'}` set. Those presets are then stored in `BlenderPrefsLocation\scripts\presets\operator`, named after the operator they refer to. Fine.

What I'd like to do is: Operator `A` has created a preset called `file.A`. From operator `B`, I'd like to re-use said preset. The property structure matches, so technically it would be possible.

At the moment, my only way of achieving this is to duplicate the folder `file.A`, and name it `file.B`, but I'd need to repeat this every time a preset is created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Leveraging the preset system**

A while back when doing some addon maintenance, changed the preset code for the add curve extra objects addon for 2.7x.  In particular add curve spirals.

Can leverage off the existing preset code to emulate the `'PRESET'` option.  This way can choose what goes in the preset, what folder to save in, the menu and the operator to execute the preset.

Code snippets from *`/2.79/scripts/addons/add_curve_extra_objects/add_curve_spirals.py`*

Firstly there is an add preset base base class to inherit

```
from bl_operators.presets import AddPresetBase
```

The operator that creates the presets, notice can set the subdir here, defines in the script,  and what properties to save in the preset.  It is also associated with a menu.

```
class CURVE_EXTRAS_OT_spirals_presets(AddPresetBase, Operator):
    bl_idname = "curve_extras.spiral_presets"
    bl_label = "Spirals"
    bl_description = "Spirals Presets"
    preset_menu = "OBJECT_MT_spiral_curve_presets"
    preset_subdir = "curve_extras/curve.spirals"

    preset_defines = [
            "op = bpy.context.active_operator",
            ]
    preset_values = [
            "op.spiral_type",
            "op.curve_type",
            "op.spiral_direction",
            "op.turns",
            "op.steps",
            "op.radius",
            "op.dif_z",
            "op.dif_radius",
            "op.B_force",
            "op.inner_radius",
            "op.dif_inner_radius",
            "op.cycles",
            "op.curves_number",
            "op.touch",
            ]
```

its associated menu class. The `bpy.types.Menu` class has a 'draw_preset(..)` class method that draws the menu from the files in the presets folder. The default preset execute operator, which runs the code within the preset file setting the props is assigned as the operator of each menu item.

```
class OBJECT_MT_spiral_curve_presets(Menu):
    '''Presets for curve.spiral'''
    bl_label = "Spiral Curve Presets"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_spiral_curve_presets"
    preset_subdir = "curve_extras/curve.spirals"
    preset_operator = "script.execute_preset"

    draw = bpy.types.Menu.draw_preset
```

In the draw method of the operator that the presets are for

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    col = layout.column_flow(align=True)

    col.label("Presets:")

    row = col.row(align=True)
    row.menu("OBJECT_MT_spiral_curve_presets",
             text=bpy.types.OBJECT_MT_spiral_curve_presets.bl_label)
    row.operator("curve_extras.spiral_presets", text="", icon='ZOOMIN')
    op = row.operator("curve_extras.spiral_presets", text="", icon='ZOOMOUT')
    op.remove_active = True
```

With this set up  presets are being saved to or loaded  from the defined folder. This way if your operators A and B have similar (same) structure can draw their presets from the same folder.

*Also Look for code in addon prefs in `__init__.py` to convert from the old preset locations to new presets.*

Comment: nice, will test this hopefully today

Comment: this *almost* works. The functionality is there, the presets are shared. The only problem I face is that this preset system seems to ignore an environment variable I set (BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS) on Blender 2.80. It saves and loads the presets from `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\presets` instead of my custom scripts path

Comment: I've tried using `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) , 'my_addon')` to work around it, but absolute paths are not allowed it seems. Is there a magic flag I missed?

Comment: Rusty on this.  Pretty sure all the pertinent code  is available as python in `bl_operators.presets`  . Is expected path set via EV same as `bpy.utils.script_path_user()` and or showing in `bpy.utils.script_paths("presets")` ?

Comment: Was just browsing `class AddPresetBase:` from `release/scripts/startup/bl_operators` in the Blender source code. There they construct the file path from `bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', target_path, create=True)` which technically would yield the correct path (it does so when run from a blender console). Not sure why this fails on inheritance.

Comment: ahhhhh... now I see it: `bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', create=False)` yields the correct path. `bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', 'test', create=False)` defaults back to the AppData blah blah one... Must be a Blender bug?

Comment: Both `bpy.utils.script_paths("presets")` and `bpy.utils.script_path_user()` work, but the first one returns two locations as a list, having the one I want ordered last. I've created a bug report https://developer.blender.org/T62736 to see what the devs think about this.