# Way for save or store by StringProperty (Preset) all the class PropertyGroup

Tags: python

I'm writing a script, now I'd like to understand how these properties can be saved, the properties are stored in a class `PropPerSet(bpy.types.PropertyGroup)`, I put a `StringProperty` as input to give a name to the preset, 1 button operator for save 1 button operator to delete current preset, and an `EnumProperty` for a list of options, the class is based on `Scene.scene_check_set = bpy.props.PointerProperty (type = PropPerSet)`, it is possible to save in a text file, or better other solutions ?

Edit 1:
This is my idea input is StringProperty, dropdown menu is only example i put manually in enum "My preset 1":
[image]

Comment: You may add another two operators to save and load those properties as dict by encoded to JSON format files, which is more flexible when you want to exchange in other program and read it directly from text.

Comment: @Hikariztw, ty know any way to find an example for store and save my Scene.scene_check_set = bpy.props.PointerProperty (type = PropPerSet)?

Comment: Related. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134613/can-python-operator-presets-be-shared-between-operators/134620#134620  define scene in preset defines `scene = bpy.context.scene` and `scene.scene_check_set.foo` etc in values.

Comment: @batFINGER, ty 
the concept is not very clear to me, for example, after setting the parameters in the UI panel I would like to save these parameters in a file or somewhere else, I would like these presets to be recalled via (I think) a drop down list, for now I have created an EnumPropery ... but I don't think it's the right way, the example you indicated is what I need? I have to put name in preset for example 'My preset 1" "My Preset 2" by Stringproperty