# How do I change the default settings of export operators?

Tags: python, export, customization

I made a panel with an Export Modified Model STL button. Right now I am using...

```
class Export_STL(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "diamond.export_stl"
    bl_label = "Export Modified Model STL"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        self.report({'INFO'}, f"This is {self.bl_idname}")
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

It works but I need the default settings to have "Batch Mode" to Object" and a check on the "Selection Only". How do I write this in the script?

Answer (score 4):

**Overwrite the menu function**

[image]

*Firstly, for the simplest approach, [assigning default via UI is the goto option](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211946/15543) IIRC have seen others suggesting similar elsewhere*

Here we will use the little used, but very handy `Menu._dyn_ui_initialize()` method to expose the list where methods are appended / prepended.

Running thru and printing the functions module and name reveals,

```
bl_ui.space_topbar draw
io_scene_fbx menu_func_export
io_anim_bvh menu_func_export
io_mesh_ply menu_func_export
io_scene_obj menu_func_export
io_mesh_stl menu_export
io_scene_gltf2 menu_func_export
io_scene_x3d menu_func_export
```

so let's simply find the old one and replace with draw from [@Gorgeous' answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211946/15543).

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import TOPBAR_MT_file_export
   
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    op = layout.operator("export_mesh.stl", text="My Custom STL Exporter")
    op.use_selection = True
    op.batch_mode = 'OBJECT'
    
funcs = TOPBAR_MT_file_export._dyn_ui_initialize()

for i, f in enumerate(funcs):
    if f.__module__ == "io_mesh_stl":
        funcs[i] = draw
        break
```

**Editing or Copying the source**

Another option is to edit original addon source, or  copy the source to our own addons folder give the addon a new name. Disable the original and enable our edited copy.

IMO editing the original source, (and even making a copy)  is a slippery slope and should be avoided as it may need to be re-edited for each blender update.

**Stealing annotations**

Since the advent of 2.8 and the introduction of annotated properties, these can be easily "pinched" from the defining class.

Can very simply make a propertygroup or an operator or a preset (emulate 'PRESET' in operator options).

Here is the set of definitions illustrated in @Gorgeoous' answer

```
>>> from io_mesh_stl import ExportSTL
>>> for k, v in ExportSTL.__annotations__.items():
...     k, v
...     
('filter_glob', (<built-in function StringProperty>, {'default': '*.stl', 'options': {'HIDDEN'}, 'attr': 'filter_glob'}))
('use_selection', (<built-in function BoolProperty>, {'name': 'Selection Only', 'description': 'Export selected objects only', 'default': False, 'attr': 'use_selection'}))
('global_scale', (<built-in function FloatProperty>, {'name': 'Scale', 'min': 0.01, 'max': 1000.0, 'default': 1.0, 'attr': 'global_scale'}))
('use_scene_unit', (<built-in function BoolProperty>, {'name': 'Scene Unit', 'description': "Apply current scene's unit (as defined by unit scale) to exported data", 'default': False, 'attr': 'use_scene_unit'}))
('ascii', (<built-in function BoolProperty>, {'name': 'Ascii', 'description': 'Save the file in ASCII file format', 'default': False, 'attr': 'ascii'}))
('use_mesh_modifiers', (<built-in function BoolProperty>, {'name': 'Apply Modifiers', 'description': 'Apply the modifiers before saving', 'default': True, 'attr': 'use_mesh_modifiers'}))
('batch_mode', (<built-in function EnumProperty>, {'name': 'Batch Mode', 'items': (('OFF', 'Off', 'All data in one file'), ('OBJECT', 'Object', 'Each object as a file')), 'attr': 'batch_mode'}))
('axis_forward', (<built-in function EnumProperty>, {'name': 'Forward', 'items': (('X', 'X Forward', ''), ('Y', 'Y Forward', ''), ('Z', 'Z Forward', ''), ('-X', '-X Forward', ''), ('-Y', '-Y Forward', ''), ('-Z', '-Z Forward', '')), 'default': 'Y', 'update': <function orientation_helper.<locals>.wrapper.<locals>._update_axis_forward at 0x7f26dc2fd9d0>, 'attr': 'axis_forward'}))
('axis_up', (<built-in function EnumProperty>, {'name': 'Up', 'items': (('X', 'X Up', ''), ('Y', 'Y Up', ''), ('Z', 'Z Up', ''), ('-X', '-X Up', ''), ('-Y', '-Y Up', ''), ('-Z', '-Z Up', '')), 'default': 'Z', 'update': <function orientation_helper.<locals>.wrapper.<locals>._update_axis_up at 0x7f26dc2fd
```

**Preset Example**

This doesn't change the default, but is a one time one menu choice to set multiple defaults quickly.

[image]

As an example am going to run over [Preset System Error](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209877/preset-system-error) and make presets for the mesh export stl operator.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, Menu
from bl_operators.presets import AddPresetBase
from io_mesh_stl import ExportSTL

class ExportSTLPresetMenu(Menu):
    bl_label = "STL Export"
    preset_subdir = ExportSTL.bl_idname
    preset_operator = "script.execute_preset"
    #draw = Menu.draw_preset
    def draw(self, context):
        self.draw_preset(context)
        

class ExportSTLPresetOperator(AddPresetBase, Operator):
    '''Save STL Export Settings'''
    bl_idname = "export_stl.preset"
    bl_label = "STL Export Settings"
    preset_menu = "ExportSTLPresetMenu"

    # variable used for all preset values
    preset_defines = [
        "op  = bpy.context.active_operator"

    ]
    
    # properties to store in the preset
    preset_values = [ 
        f"op.{k}" 
        for k in ExportSTL.__annotations__.keys()

    ]

    # where to store the preset
    preset_subdir = ExportSTL.bl_idname
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True 

# Display into an existing panel
def panel_func(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    
    
    row = layout.row(align=True)
    
    row.menu(ExportSTLPresetMenu.__name__, text=ExportSTLPresetMenu.bl_label)
    
    row.operator(ExportSTLPresetOperator.bl_idname, text="", icon='ZOOM_IN')
    row.operator(ExportSTLPresetOperator.bl_idname, text="", icon='ZOOM_OUT').remove_active = True


classes = (
    ExportSTLPresetMenu,
    ExportSTLPresetOperator,
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.STL_PT_export_main.prepend(panel_func)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    bpy.types.STL_PT_export_main.remove(panel_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

*TODO Messed up menu class name naming convention, requires edit.*

This creates a preset `Batch_Sel.py` in your `presets/export_mesh.stl` folder , TODO perhaps could be in `presets/operators/export_mesh.stl` )

```
import bpy
op  = bpy.context.active_operator

op.filter_glob = '*.stl'
op.use_selection = True
op.global_scale = 1.0
op.use_scene_unit = False
op.ascii = True
op.use_mesh_modifiers = True
op.batch_mode = 'OFF'
op.axis_forward = 'Y'
op.axis_up = 'Z'
```

*Revealing an oops, get eyest ttestted moment in GIF that I set ASCII, instead of batch, but you get the drift*

**Make a new op from old.**

*Will run thru the very basic theory here, rather than add a MWE*

Similarly to above can very quickly make a new operator from original using

```
from io_mesh_stl import ExportSTL

new_op_class = type(
        "MyNewSTLExporter",
        (ExportSTL, Operator),
        change_dictionary,
        )
```

where change dictionary property : value keys we wish to change from the original. Eg to just change the label

```
change_dictionary = {"bl_label", "My STL Export"}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need to write a custom operator to re-use the existing one. You can call the operator in your layout and change its properties, see [How to pass multiple operator properties via UI layout?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/how-to-pass-multiple-operator-properties-via-ui-layout)

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        op = layout.operator("export_mesh.stl", text="My Custom STL Exporter")
        op.use_selection = True
        op.batch_mode = 'OBJECT'


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

You can find the operator's parameters in `your blender install path / 2.** / Scripts / addons / io_mesh_stl / __init__.py` under the `ExportSTL` class.  :

```
use_selection: BoolProperty(
    name="Selection Only",
    description="Export selected objects only",
    default=False,
)
global_scale: FloatProperty(
    name="Scale",
    min=0.01, max=1000.0,
    default=1.0,
)
use_scene_unit: BoolProperty(
    name="Scene Unit",
    description="Apply current scene's unit (as defined by unit scale) to exported data",
    default=False,
)
ascii: BoolProperty(
    name="Ascii",
    description="Save the file in ASCII file format",
    default=False,
)
use_mesh_modifiers: BoolProperty(
    name="Apply Modifiers",
    description="Apply the modifiers before saving",
    default=True,
)
batch_mode: EnumProperty(
    name="Batch Mode",
    items=(
        ('OFF', "Off", "All data in one file"),
        ('OBJECT', "Object", "Each object as a file"),
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for all your information. I see your example is for a properties button. I tried to adapt it to work with my View_3d button but it did not work. Could you help me make it work for this?